# C++ floating point exception

Tags: исключения, c++

```
float y = 0;
try {
    y = 1 / y;
} catch (exception& ex) {
}
```

Как ловить такой exception? У меня не ловится почему-то(юзаю gnu c++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что тут по-любому всё хорошо. Это int нельзя на целый ноль делить, а если в выражении есть float или double, то всё поднимается до float или double и в результате выходит либо бесконечность, либо NaN (0.0/0).

А вообще вот [Catch a divide by zero error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747934/c-catch-a-divide-by-zero-error)

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Подобные низкоуровневые исключения (уровня исключений ЦПУ) по стандарту не отлавливаются. Это принципиальная позиция Страуструпа с самого начала истории С++. Программист должен сам заботиться об их предотвращении.

Comment: Формально да, но с помощью слушателя сигналов можно обработчик привязать: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747934/c-catch-a-divide-by-zero-error

Comment: Понятно, спасибо за ссылку, но это уже несколько другой прием отлова, основанный на системном программировании, а не средствами С++, естественно, системнозависимый.